react-native-background-actions is Not working with Android 14 App Crash issue
Android version details:-
buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
minSdkVersion = 23
compileSdkVersion = 34
targetSdkVersion = 34
ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
kotlinVersion = "1.9.22"

package version details:-
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.74.2",
"react-native-background-actions": "^4.0.0",

Getting Error:-

